# Rails 4 - Send desktop notifications using 'notify-send' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, notifications

In rails 4 project, I am trying to send desktop notifications using `notify-send` command. This command will send notification to only current system, how can I send to other system by using it? Also please explain on what basis we can get other system's information so that we can mention that it in `notify-send` command.

I have written a rake task so that it will check continuously and send notifications.
Right now I am using below command for testing in localhost,

```
system "notify-send 'Title' 'Message' -t 2000"
```

Please help me to solve this issue and it should works in all environments.

Comment: Do you expect `notify-send` executed on server side ruby _to show notifications on client computers_?!

Comment: Yes. It should run on server side and notifications should send to related client systems.

Comment: It's impossible. You should use websockets for it. Just the first link in google: https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-notifications

Comment: I have tried this task using other gems but it didn't work. I asked this to know whether we can customize this command or not?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053647/rails-4-notifyor-gem-is-not-sending-any-notifications